# How can i access camera module from iotedge module using azure IOTEDGE

Tags: python, azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-iot-edge

I am using following code in my docker file for video streaming

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
#fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
total_frame=0
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print(ret)
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    #frame = cv.flip(frame, 0)

    #video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(time_string, fourcc, 30.0, (1280, 720))
    # write the flipped frame


# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
#cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

`

I am using this dockerfile for above code

```
FROM ubuntu

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -yq \ 
    python3 \
    python3-pip \   
  && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip 
RUN pip3 install imutils
RUN pip3 install azure-iot-device
RUN pip3 install opencv-contrib-python

WORKDIR /main/

COPY main .

CMD ["python3", "/main/main.py"]
```

I can access the video source on host using docker run --device /dev/video0 image
but I cannot  access the camera when I deploy it as IOTEDGE module?Please tell How can I access the video source from the iotedge module on hostsystem.The location of cv2.VideoCapture(0) is cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With any container, including IoT Edge Modules, you need to expose the /dev/videoX to the container.  With IoT Edge Modules, this is done with a Container Create Option.

Search for /dev/video0 here: https://kevinsaye.wordpress.com/2018/04/16/creating-an-opencv-module-for-iot-edge/ to see how it is done.